# Problem downloading file from backend to frontend

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have developed an app with ASP.net core 6 and angular 13,
my problem is in the link for file download for the API, it throws error in frontend code.
code  service in angular:

```
private baseUrl='https://localhost:7125/api';
getFilePath(url:string){
  return `${this.baseUrl}/${url}`;
}
```

code TS File:

```
public   setFile(): void {
//this.AllDemande.fileUrl : url link form database
      if(this.AllDemande.fileUrl=!null){
     this.DisplayFileUrl= this.congeService.getFilePath(this.AllDemande.fileUrl);
       }
      else{
       this.DisplayFileUrl='assets/pdf.png';

      }
    }
```

in capture screeen when i want to take link of file pdf it dispaly link from angular server not from api[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the problem you can see link of pdf it dispaly server of front-end and with i change it manuly in browser it work